# Change default DynamoDB .NET SDK behavior to store DateTime as Unix time

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-dynamodb, iso

By default, DynamoDB converts .NET `DateTime` to a string type (S) and stores dates in ISO-8601 format. See [supported data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html). The problem is .NET captures 7 digits for ticks whereas ISO-8601 stores 3. So, if I were to store a `DateTime`, fetch the entity, and compare the .NET date to what is fetched (for example in a test), this will fail.

`TimeOfDay` comparisons:

```
15:28:21.4731507 (.NET)
15:28:21.473 (DynamoDB)
```

Another problem I see is the `DynamoDB` SDK will convert UTC to local time when items are being retrieved. See a [reported issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1450) with a [workaround](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1450#issuecomment-875523583). The suggested fix does not work for me. The converter will successfully convert the date via `ToUniversalTime()`, but it seems the returned value is being ignored. Thus, I still get a local time.

I'd like to avoid storing dates in ISO-8601. I know that I can store the ticks as a `long` property in my entities. This eliminates both problems described above. The caveat is I won't be able to use a `DateTime` property type anywhere in my entities going forward.

This brings me to my question. Is it possible to override the default SDK behavior so that `DateTime` is stored as a number type (N) in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address the issue of truncated ticks, you can use the "o" [date format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings), which is the "round trip" date format, for this exact scenario. The GitHub example wasn't specifying a format in its `ToEntry` lambda, so I believe it was further truncating information when `ToString()` was then called without any format information.

You can modify the sample in GitHub like so:

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IPropertyConverter
    {
        public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
        {
            DateTime? dateTimeValue = value as DateTime?;
            if (dateTimeValue == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            string dateTimeString = dateTimeValue?.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o");
            DynamoDBEntry entry = new Primitive
            {
                Value = dateTimeString,
            };
            return entry;
        }

        public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
        {
            Primitive primitive = entry as Primitive;
            if (primitive == null || !(primitive.Value is string) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)primitive.Value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }

            string dateTimeString = primitive.Value as string;
            DateTime dateTimeValue = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString).ToUniversalTime();

            return dateTimeValue;
        }
    }
```

Few things to note here:

- We're calling `ToString` with `"o"` to get the round-trip format
- We force to UniversalTime before we call `ToString("o");` to get the "Z" format of the string instead of the offset format no matter if you pass a `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Utc` in.
- We force to UniversalTime in `FromEntry` as well, since you seemed to want to use Utc. When comparing `DateTime`, it's always worth comparing `.Kind` as well.

We still add this to our context, as in the GitHub example:

```
context.ConverterCache.Add(typeof(DateTime), new CustomDateTimeConverter());
```

Note the impact that setting the output `DateTimeKind` has via this example:

```
var utcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
// Create a book.
DimensionType myBookDimensions = new DimensionType()
{
    Length = 8M,
    Height = 11M,
    Thickness = 0.5M,
};

Book utcBook = new Book
{
    Id = 501,
    Title = "UtcBook",
    Isbn = "999-9999999999",
    BookAuthors = new List<string> { "Author 1", "Author 2" },
    Dimensions = myBookDimensions,
    publishedOn = utcDate,
};

var localDate = DateTime.Now;
Book localBook = new Book
{
    Id = 502,
    Title = "Local Book",
    Isbn = "999-1111",
    BookAuthors = new List<string> { "Author 1", "Author 2" },
    Dimensions = myBookDimensions,
    publishedOn = localDate,
};

// Add the book to the DynamoDB table ProductCatalog.
await context.SaveAsync(utcBook);
await context.SaveAsync(localBook);

// Retrieve the book.
Book utcBookRetrieved = await context.LoadAsync<Book>(501);
Console.WriteLine(@$"Original: {utcDate.TimeOfDay}({utcDate.Kind}) => Saved: {
    utcBookRetrieved.publishedOn.TimeOfDay}({utcBookRetrieved.publishedOn.Kind}). Equal? {
        utcDate.TimeOfDay == utcBookRetrieved.publishedOn.TimeOfDay} ToUniversal() Equal? {
            utcDate.ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay == utcBookRetrieved.publishedOn.ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay}");

Book localBookRetrieved = await context.LoadAsync<Book>(502);
Console.WriteLine(@$"Original: {localDate.TimeOfDay}({localDate.Kind}) => Saved: {
    localBookRetrieved.publishedOn.TimeOfDay}({localBookRetrieved.publishedOn.Kind}). Equal? {
        localDate.TimeOfDay == localBookRetrieved.publishedOn.TimeOfDay} ToUniversal() Equal? {
            localDate.ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay == localBookRetrieved.publishedOn.ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay}");
```

This prints:

```
Original: 20:12:52.4810270(Utc) => Saved: 20:12:52.4810270(Utc). Equal? True ToUniversal() Equal? True
Original: 15:12:52.4812120(Local) => Saved: 20:12:52.4812120(Utc). Equal? False ToUniversal() Equal? True
```

You can also use this method to export ticks, instead. Just change the ToEntry/FromEntry to convert to the number ticks.

Comment: Thanks Chris. This worked like a charm. The only addition I made was, in addition to converting `DateTime`, I had to register `typeof(DateTime?)` with the same converter to handle the nullable variant.

Comment: I'd also add I'm a fan of DateTimeOffset for datetimes where I'll be doing serialization. The mental model for it is more straightforward to me and I tend to find I have less bugs. To each their own, though!